# Problem with referencing to a newenvironment

Tags: cross-referencing, environments

The reference I'm using below doesn't work. I think I'm missing something in the definition of `myclaim`. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{claimcounter}
\numberwithin{claimcounter}{theorem}
\newenvironment{myclaim}{\stepcounter{claimcounter}{\par\noindent{\bf Claim \theclaimcounter:}}}{\par}

\begin{document}
Refering to Claim \ref{first-claim}

\begin{theorem}
aa
\end{theorem}

\begin{myclaim}
\label{first-claim}
bb
\end{myclaim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`

Comment: So simple.. So much time wasted ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `\stepcounter` with `\refstepcounter` -- this command *"[i]ncrease[s] a counter by one, also setting the value used by `\label`"* ([source2e](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf), chapter 21).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcounter{claimcounter}
\numberwithin{claimcounter}{theorem}
\newenvironment{myclaim}{\refstepcounter{claimcounter}{\par\noindent{\bf Claim \theclaimcounter:}}}{\par}

\begin{document}
Refering to Claim \ref{first-claim}

\begin{theorem}
aa
\end{theorem}

\begin{myclaim}
\label{first-claim}
bb
\end{myclaim}
\end{document}
```